# Kernel Panic, Fatal Trap 18, Pfsense WUSB54GC AP crash

Tags: wireless-access-point, pfsense, kernel-panic

I have an old system that I am converting to a pfsense router. I am trying to use a linksys/cisco WUSB54GC as the wireless device for the AP I can get it broadcasting(it uses the rum(4) drivers) but once a device tries to get an IP. I get a kernel panic. the error is fatal trap 18 divide by zero integer. What can I do to prevent this from happening on the machine most fixes I have found for freeBSD are all header changes. and I would need to recompile either the kernel or the driver. Can I get any links or tutorials to help me do this if this is the only way to solve this problem. also it is pfsense 2.0.0 and yesterday 2.0.1 came out and I will try that when I get home to see if that happens to solve the bug I am running into.

Comment: I suggest you raise this bug with the pfSense team.  They have many [mailing lists](http://www.pfsense.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=66&Itemid=71), and even offer [commercial support](http://www.pfsense.org/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=62&Itemid=73) which you should avail yourself of if you are running pfSense device in a production environment.

Comment: It is for home use currently and I always forget about mailing lists thank you very much.